# How can I delete one feed instance from my WordPress website's feed?

Tags: wordpress, feed

Hello World post has been deleted, but wherever the feed is used, feed includes the excerpt and link to the deleted post. From where can I manage all the feeds of my WordPress website?

Comment: You have to edit your content `Posts` and/or `Pages` where you have used excerpt and link to deleted posts. It cannot be done automatically.

Comment: RSS Widget is loading it. Wherever I place it. It shows the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a tonne. After searching more and specifically with 'wp_cache_feed_transient_lifetime' I got my solution, which is to wait for 12 hours.

I realized that publishing an article, updates the feed, but unpublishing doesn't automatically remove it from the feeds.

WordPress cache feed has a lifetime of 43200 seconds. You cannot get rid of the feed instance. Time can be reduced by editing the code, but I am happy with default settings.